# Redirecting to a different link when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidR menu with the contents:

```
<li class="sidr-class-dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="sidr-class-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">News</a>
    <ul class="sidr-class-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
            <a href="/website/page1">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/website/page2">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/website/page1">Page 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The href of each page is unknown, it is given an id by the cms.

Although the a class="sidr-class-dropdown-toggle"> has a href it isn't a correct link, how do I direct to the first page href when clicking on the a class.

I would like to hide the contents of sidr-class-dropdown-menu with CSS with only the a class 'sidr-class-dropdown-toggle' showing so it clicks through to the first link.

Comment: you want to hide <ul class="sidr-class-dropdown-menu>?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question accordingly, but still want the a class to direct to the first href of ul <ul class="sidr-class-dropdown-menu> > li  > a regardless of the href inside.

Comment: how do I direct to the first page href when clicking on the a class. Pls  Check if this works   <a href="#Page 1" class="sidr-class-dropdown-toggle"  > </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to capture the click event, prevent the default action, then show the menu and force a click on the first `a` element found.

```js
$('.sidr-class-dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.sidr-class-dropdown-menu').show().find('li:first-child a')[0].click();
});
```

```css
.sidr-class-dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sidr-class-dropdown-menu a:visited {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidr-class-dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="sidr-class-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">News</a>
  <ul class="sidr-class-dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: none;` to `<ul class="sidr-class-dropdown-menu>` to hide it.